# Is there a best practice to reduce latency for exchange between cores?

Tags: caching, synchronization, intel, cpu-cores

We know that in today's Intel's processors sharing between cores is via cache L3. Exchange between parts of L3 cache is on the ring bus (modified QPI), and thus latency the greater the farther the cores of each other (on the ring). Is there a best practice to reduce latency for exchange between cores?

An example: that threads between which little data exchange we combine in the single process. Then the operating system will be siting all the threads of the same process  in neighboring cores.

Comment: What is your OS? Linux for example does scheduling of each thread almost independently. I think, better solution for you is to manually bind your threads to CPU cores.

Comment: @osgx Both: Windows x64 and Linux x64. Probably require manualy set affinity. But this will require their own load-balance within the program.